# Массив в main не видно в статическом методе

Tags: массивы, java

Я новичок в Java. Изучаю этот язык только 2 недели. Наверное что-то где-то упустил. Прошу помочь мне.

```
public class Dafnia {
public static void main (String args[]) {
    int mass[] = {1, 2};
    Dafnia.method();
}   

public static void method () {
    System.out.println(mass[1]);
}
```

}

Массив `mass` не видно в статическом методе `method`
В чём дело понятия не имею.
Извините за глупый вопрос. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Массив `mass` — локальная переменная, объявленная в методе `main` и, стало быть, за его пределами не существует. Вам нужно объявить этот массив как поле класса:

```
public class Dafnia {
    private static int mass[] = {1, 2};

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        method();
    }

    public static void method () {
        System.out.println(mass[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что для использования в статическом методе объект сам должен быть статичным.

```
public class Dafnia {
    static int[] mass = new int[] {1, 2};
    public static void main (String args[]) {
       method();
    }

     public static void method () {
        System.out.println(mass[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @SuperCreeper в данном случае проблема в том, что переменная, ссылающаяся на массив, ограничена областью самого метода main.

Comment: И только за это - ? Код-то в ответах совпадает...